# Python 3, how to read from txt into 4 arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The text file looks like this:

```
421 2 1 8 34 27
421 0 0 8 37 27
435 0 1 9 8 44
435 4 0 9 10 50
```

```
for row in file_content[0:]:
    id, place, inout, hour, min, sec = row.split(" ")
print (id)
```

In the code I wanted to separate the rows, the first column contains the ids of persons, the second is ids of places, third is the person go in or out (0/1), and the last 3 is time (hour:min:sec)

Could someone help me correct this code so I could continue the practicing for my exam? (I'm a beginner)

Comment: *"i only get one random id"* No, you get the *last* one. For reasons that should be fairly obvious.

Comment: In Python, indentation demarcates the body of explicit function definitions and loops.

Comment: this is just a random code i wrote minutes ago, i cant correct it, i came here so maybe someone could really help not just say it's obvious.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("Text.txt", "r") as f:
    id, place, inout, hour, min, sec = zip(*map(str.split, f))

print(id)
# [OUT] ('421', '421', '435', '435')
```

[Zip()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip)

Comment: Or just `id, place, inout, hour, min, sec = zip(*map(str.split, f))`

Comment: Thanks, I will use this.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> filecontent =open("test.txt",'r')
>>> for row in filecontent:
...     id, place, inout, hour, min, sec = row.split(" ")
...     print("id is", id)
... 
id is 421
id is 421
id is 435
id is 435
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.